# PHP base64_encode returning incorrect results

Tags: php

I am trying to encode a token in base64 to use as an authentication token. However, `base64_encode` does not seem to be providing the correct value.

```
$encode = base64_encode("$this->access_token:");
var_dump("$this->access_token:");
var_dump($encode);
```

Result

```
string(31) "YfJF3NHGZbVUeWTVv-KtdQYV8Bwsal:"
string(44) "WWZKRjNOSEdaYlZVZVdUVnYtS3RkUVlWOEJ3c2FsOg=="
```

If I run this command on the command line it gives me the correct token that does work with the api

```
openssl base64 <<< YfJF3NHGZbVUeWTVv-KtdQYV8Bwsal:
WWZKRjNOSEdaYlZVZVdUVnYtS3RkUVlWOEJ3c2FsOgo=
WWZKRjNOSEdaYlZVZVdUVnYtS3RkUVlWOEJ3c2FsOg== (php result for comparison)
```

Another example

```
EIiLMhGNib9JNH2ob62JpsoQoVNRdltc: (access token)
RUlpTE1oR05pYjlKTkgyb2I2Mkpwc29Rb1ZOUmRsdGM6Cg== (openssl)
RUlpTE1oR05pYjlKTkgyb2I2Mkpwc29Rb1ZOUmRsdGM6     (php)
```

Comment: Shouldn't `base64_encode("$this->access_token:");` be `base64_encode($this->access_token);`? No quotes.

Comment: Well I tried it on javascript and it returns same as PHP.

Comment: I need the colon for basic auth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get it. Your `openssl` is taking in account of a newline character at the end. Your PHP code is fine and you should go with that only.

Actually:

```
EIiLMhGNib9JNH2ob62JpsoQoVNRdltc:
<newline>
```

converts to what you see in openssl and `EIiLMhGNib9JNH2ob62JpsoQoVNRdltc:` converts to what you see in PHP.

Comment: That did it, thanks just had to add `\n` to it, `$encode = base64_encode("$this->access_token:\n");`